# QGIS model algorithm "Load layer into project" wont allow layer to be loaded more than once

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

I am creating a model which saves a polygon layer as geopackage in a project folder. I then want to load that layer into the project several times and apply different style files to each layer to show different aspects of the data. If using the "load layer into project" algorithm several times on the same source file I find only the last one in the model appears in the project. I have tried many combinations of dependency but nothing seems to work. Using QGIS 3.22

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding some processing step prior to loading the layer.

Although this is creating a new temp layer, maybe that wont work for you.

I've added Refactor fields without changing any fields:

[image]

Comment: Thanks I will try that. I am working with vector data but it may not make a differnce, I see you have used the "export layers information" step too. That might be useful. Will test it thankyou

Comment: Yes! this worked for me. I get temp layers but that doesnt matter. I can work with this now which is such a relief!